# How to fix view automatically scrolled up on mouse drag and then reset automatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have added two user control to the project. One is for portrait and other is for landscape because my views in both mode are different. Now according to the orientation of view page i add the user control.

Scenario :

When application loaded now i drag mouse over the user control then the user control scrolls according to the mouse move. When i releases the mouse button then view automatically scrolls back to the original position. I want to stop this behavior and why is this happening.

Comment: Have you placed the ScrollViewer inside the control or the control inside the ScrollViewer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the ScrollViewer in the right place, say it is attached to your page instead of your control, then your mouse movements may be getting caught by the page instead. That would be why you are getting that effect, the scrolling is reaching the bottom of the page. Make sure the ScrollViewer is in the right place.

If you don't have a ScrollViewer, then make sure you add one so that you will be to scroll in the control